# Hashing function security level required for storing passwords

Tags: hash, cryptography, password-protection, password-hash, password-storage

I am working on a project that has to store users passwords. With that password you can gain access to a user achievements and stuff so it's really important that you can not get the password even if you hacked into the database. My problem is which hashing function to choose in security and efficiency level.

Right now I am using sha256 with salt and pepper but I read that using a slow hashing function like Bcrypt with cost factor of 12 can be superior. And if it does, how much more security do I gain from using a pepper as well because it's really time consuming for hash function like Bcrypt.

My question is what hash function should I use base on the assumption that I do not expect to get hacked by a global hacking organization with supercomputers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain crypto hash functions like sha2 or sha3 don't cut it anymore for password hashing, because it's too efficient to compute them, which means an attacker that controls many cpu cores can compute large tables relatively quickly. In practice the feasibility of this still depends on the length of passwords mostly (and the character set used in those password to some extent), but you should still not use these unless you *really* know why that will be acceptable.

Instead, you should be using a hash or key derivation function more suitable for password hashing. Pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2 are all acceptable candidates, with somewhat different strengths and weaknesses. For a regular web app, it almost doesn't matter which of these you choose, and all will be more secure than plain hashes.

The difference will be very real if your database is compromised, properly hashed passwords will likely not be revealed, while at least some passwords with sha likely will, despite salt and pepper.

Comment: the pssword is a random generated string that I control his length.
for example that can be a valid password for sha256 with salt and pepper (64 characters):
"DL*t+g|p-4/-*=iU0WuhE]:@[zq]j$AW)X]<';;5/ud7X(\qT>zF/zKyN0vn)vQp".

Comment: hashing that password and storing it is secure enough or shuld I use bcrypt after all.

Comment: And if bcrypt is better in my case, where I can control the length and distribution of characters randomly, what password length is the most secure for this algorithm, and should I still use pepper? Because with pepper it can take to my server up to 14 seconds to compare this hash.

Comment: @roee - A pepper does not add noticeable time to the calculation, it is the cost factor of a password-hash function which controls the time. The password-hash functions mentioned above are designed for relatively "weak" user password, the strong "password" you gave (if really random) wouldn't need salt, pepper or a special hash algorithm at all. But as soon as the password can be choosen by the user, a password-hash function is mandatory.